# Detemining variance of the normal r.v. from 2 points on the cdf

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a Normal random variable with parameters $\mu=b$ and $\sigma^2=c$, knowing that $P(X\le 10)=0.996$ and that $P(X \le 3)=0.2946$. Find $c$.

**MY WORK**

I think the question lacks data. I know I will find value of $c$ by using the property of pdf that it is equal to $1$ when integrated over the given domain. But I don't know how to proceed further. What is the use of $P(X\le 3)=0.2946$ and $P(X\le 10)=0.996$.please Can anyone guide or hint me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Y = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so $X = Y\sigma + \mu$ and we have
$$
0.2946
 = \mathbb{P}[X \le 3]
 = \mathbb{P}[Y\sigma + \mu \le 3]
 = \mathbb{P}[Y \le (3 - \mu)/\sigma]
 = \Phi((3-\mu)/\sigma)
$$
and now if you look up $\Phi^{-1}(0.2946)$ and do the same with the other point, you get 2 equations in 2 unknowns for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: how do i find inverse of $CDF$ evaluated $0.2946$ from table sir.

Comment: @Ameer786 solution from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+standard+normal+cdf+of+x++%3D%3D+0.2946) on the bottom